# How to get the required injections from a @Inject constructor without creating an injector?

Tags: guice, inspection

I'm toying around with Guice Introspection in the hopes of building a library that auto-checks guice bindings and requirements as a unit test and pretty prints missing bindings for easier Guicing.

I wrote up a quick ElementVisitor, but I noticed that while the visitor finds and captures @Provider requirements just fine, I don't get any visited elements for bound types with @Inject constructors. Is there a good way to grab these dependencies without building a full injector?

Alternatively, is there an open source library that does something like this already?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(Your.class).getDependencies()`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/spi/InjectionPoint.html#forConstructorOf-java.lang.Class-) to get the dependencies associated with the injectable constructor of a particular class.

Alternatively, create an `Injector` in `Stage.TOOL`.